# Why is index not changing after returning to parent after executing child process

Tags: c, shell, operating-system, fork

I am trying to implement a simple shell with history which takes process batch files as input and execute them.

My header file `head.h` looks like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef struct Process{
    int index;
    char **args;
} Proc_t;

typedef struct historyNode{
    Proc_t Process;
    struct historyNode *next;
    struct historyNode * prev;
} his_t; 

//Function Prototypes
his_t * createNode(his_t *head, Proc_t *Process);
char** ParseString(char *buffer);
void execProcess(his_t *head, Proc_t *Process);
void HistoryBrief(his_t *head);
void HistoryFull(his_t *head);
void printProcess(Proc_t Process);
void printProcessCmd(Proc_t Process);
int isNumber(char *arg);
Proc_t *get_Process(his_t *head, int index);  
Proc_t *existsInHistory(his_t *head, char **args);
```

Here is the `main.c` :

```
#include "head.h"

his_t * head = NULL;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int index = 1;
    
    for(int i = 1 ; i<argc;i++)
    {
        char buffer[1000]; // to store the command read from file
        FILE *f = fopen(argv[i],"r");
        while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer), f) != NULL)
        {
            char** currProcessArgs = ParseString(buffer);
            Proc_t *currProcess = (Proc_t *)malloc(sizeof(Proc_t));
            currProcess->index = index;
            //printf("index of currProcess: %d\n",currProcess->index);  
            currProcess->args = currProcessArgs;
            //printProcess(*currProcess);
      
            if(head == NULL)    
            {    
                head = createNode(head, currProcess);
                //printf("Process name:%s, head address:%p\n", head, head->Process.args[0]);
           
            }
            else
            {
                createNode(head, currProcess);
                //printf("Process name:%s, head address:%p\n", head, head->Process.args[0]);
            }
           printf("\n%d index in loop\n", index);
           index++;
            execProcess(head,currProcess);
           //index++;
        }
    
       // HistoryBrief(head);
        //HistoryFull(head);
        fclose(f);
    }
    //Ignore the while part for now
    while(1)
    {
        char inputBuffer[1000];
        puts("Please enter a command!: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", inputBuffer);
        //fflush(stdin);
        printf("inputBuffer: %s\n",inputBuffer);
        char **userCmdArgs = ParseString(inputBuffer);
        if(strcmp(userCmdArgs[0],"EXEC")==0)
        {   
            if(isNumber(userCmdArgs[1])==0)
            {    
                Proc_t *userCmd = (Proc_t *)malloc(sizeof(Proc_t));
                userCmd->index=index;
                userCmd->args = userCmdArgs+1;
                userCmd = existsInHistory(head, userCmd->args);
                if(userCmd!=NULL)
                {
                    puts("This Command Already exists in History!!");    
                   // execProcess(userCmd);
                }
                else    
                {
                    puts("This Command doesn't exist in history. Adding it to the history");
                    createNode(head,userCmd);
                    //execProcess(userCmd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Proc_t *userProcessWithIndex = get_Process(head, atoi(userCmdArgs[1]));
                if(userProcessWithIndex==NULL)
                {    
                    puts("Command with the given index doesn't exist!!\n");
                }
                else
                    execProcess(head, userProcessWithIndex);
            }
        }
        else if(strcmp(userCmdArgs[0], "HISTORY")==0)
        {    
            if(strcmp(userCmdArgs[1],"BRIEF")==0)
            {    
                printProcess(head->Process);        
                HistoryBrief(head);
            }
            else
            {    
                HistoryFull(head); 
            }
        }
        else if(strcmp(userCmdArgs[0],"STOP")==0)
        {
            puts("Exiting Normally, Bye!!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

here is `history.c`

```
#include "head.h"

his_t *createNode(his_t *head, Proc_t *Process)
{
    his_t * new_node = (his_t *) malloc(sizeof(his_t)); 
    new_node->Process = *Process;
    
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->prev = NULL;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new_node;
        return head;
    }   
    else 
    {
        his_t * temp = head;
        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next=new_node;
        new_node->prev=temp;
        return new_node;
    }
}
Proc_t *existsInHistory(his_t *head, char **args)
{
    his_t *temp = head;
    int i = 0;
    int exists = 1;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        while(args[i]!=NULL && temp->Process.args[i]!=NULL)
        {
            if(args[i]==temp->Process.args[i])
                exists=1;
            else
            {
                exists = 0;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(exists)
        {
            Proc_t *tempProc = (Proc_t *)malloc(sizeof(Proc_t));
            tempProc = &(temp->Process);
            return tempProc;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
        return NULL;
    }
}
Proc_t *get_Process(his_t *head, int index)
{
    his_t * temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {   
        if(temp->Process.index == index)
            break;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {   
        Proc_t *procTemp = (Proc_t *)malloc(sizeof(Proc_t));
        procTemp = &(temp->Process);
        return procTemp;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
void HistoryBrief(his_t *head)
{
    his_t * temp = head;

    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Address of head: %p\n", temp);
        if(temp->prev!=NULL)    
            printProcessCmd(temp->prev->Process);
        printProcessCmd(temp->Process);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void HistoryFull(his_t *head)
{
    his_t *temp = head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        printProcess(temp->Process);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}

}
```

Here is `process.c`

```
#include "head.h"

int isNumber(char *arg)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(arg[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(isdigit(arg[i])==0)
            return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
char** ParseString(char *buffer)
{
    int buff_size = strlen(buffer);
    if(buffer[buff_size-1]=='\n')
        buffer[buff_size-1]='\0'; 
    char **args =(char *)malloc(30*sizeof(char *));// array for storing arguments
    int i = 0;
    char *arg = strtok(buffer," ");
    while(arg !='\0')
    {
        args[i] = arg;
        arg = strtok(NULL," ");
        i++;
    }
    args[i] = '\0';
    puts("\n");
    int k =0;
    while(args[k]!=NULL)
    {    
        printf("%s ",args[k]);
        k++;    
    }
    

    return args;
      
}
void printProcess(Proc_t Process)
{
    printf("%d.",Process.index);
    puts("args: ");
    int i = 0;
    while(Process.args[i]!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ",Process.args[i]);
        i++;
    }
    puts("\n");
}

void printProcessCmd(Proc_t Process)
{
    printf("%d.%s\n",Process.index,Process.args[0]);
}

void execProcess(his_t *head,Proc_t *Process)
{
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {    
        printf("Currently Executing: index:%d||command:%s\n\n",Process->index, Process->args[0]);
        execvp(Process->args[0],Process->args);

    }
    else if(pid)
    {    
        wait(NULL);
        (head->Process.index)++;
        printf("index of head afgter returning to parent process: %d\n",head->Process.index);  
        printf("%s, cmd of head process after returning to parent\n",head->Process.args[0]);
    }
    else
        return 0;    
}
```

So basically my program will take input as text files containing linux commands. Each command is written on a different line.

Example file -

```
ls -al 
echo Hello World
touch newfile.c
ps
```

I have created a doubly linked list for storing history of commands.
When I call `HistoryBrief()` It prints 4 `ps` instead of printing each command. Also, after calling fork, the index is changing inside the parent but not the child. Why is that??

Comment: You keep reusing the same array for the values pointed to by the argument arrays you're storing.

Comment: @Shawn Can you elaborate, I couldn't understand.

Comment: 'if(args[i]==temp->Process.args[i])' - comparing pointers instead of strings, (same issue as above, really).

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for pointing out the mistake, I will use strcmp() instead of == but the thing is I am still not able to understand where I am reusing the argument arrays. Can you please help?

Comment: Regarding: `Proc_t *procTemp = (Proc_t *)malloc(sizeof(Proc_t));
        procTemp = &(temp->Process);` This is declaring a pointer, setting that pointer to point to some allocated memory, then overlaying that pointer (results in a memory leak)